# Ayuda con una tabla dentro de un while php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, while

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
//PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS
  $resultado_estadistica .= "<h4>ESTADISTICA DE PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS</h4>";

  $resultado_estadistica .= '<table id="estadistica" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Mes</th> 
  <th>Ventas Mensual</th>
  <th>Mensualidades </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';

  while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_epe)){

    $dateGroup = $l['dateGroup'];
    $monto_total = $l['monto_total'];
    $venta_mensual = number_format($monto_total, 2, ',', '.');

    $resultado_estadistica .= '<tr>';
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'.$dateGroup.'</td>
      <td>'.$venta_mensual .' BsS'.'</td>';
      while ($j = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_apa)) 
      {
        $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'. $j['monto_total2'] .' BsS</td></tr>';
      } 
      $resultado_estadistica .= '</td></tr>';
  }   

  $resultado_estadistica .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Mi idea es hacer que la variable `$j['monto_total2']` se enliste en la ultima columna de mi tabla y no se como hacerlo y he intentado ya varias opciones.

**Lo que me gustaria lograr:**

```
Mes       Ventas Mensual       Mensualidades
enero      10                   20 
febrero    10                   10
marzo      10                   30
```

Aplicando la sugerencia tengo como resultado lo siguiente:

```
//PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS
  $resultado_estadistica .= "<h4>ESTADISTICA DE PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS</h4>";

  $resultado_estadistica .= '<table id="estadistica" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Mes</th> 
  <th>Ventas Mensual</th>
  <th>Mensualidades </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_VE.UTF-8');
  while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_epe)){

    $dateGroup = strtoupper($l['dateGroup']);
    $monto_total = $l['monto_total'];
    $venta_mensual = number_format($monto_total, 2, ',', '.');

    $resultado_estadistica .= '<tr>';
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'.$dateGroup.'</td>
      <td>'.$venta_mensual .' BsS'.'</td>';
      while ($j = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_apa)) 
      {
        $monto_total2 = $j['monto_total2'];
        $m = number_format($monto_total2, 2, ',', '.');

        $resultado_estadistica .= '<td colspan="3" align="right">'.$m .' BsS</td></tr>';
      } 
     //$resultado_estadistica .= ' ';
  }   

  $resultado_estadistica .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Y esta es la salida en el navegador:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="estadistica" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Mes</th> 
  <th>Ventas Mensual</th>
  <th>Mensualidades </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>ENERO 2019</td>
      <td>10,00 BsS</td><td colspan="3" align="right">10,00 BsS</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" align="right">10,00 BsS</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" align="right">100,00 BsS</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" align="right">10,00 BsS</td></tr><tr><td>DICIEMBRE 2018</td>
      <td>10,00 BsS</td></tr><tr><td>NOVIEMBRE 2018</td>
      <td>10,00 BsS</td></tr><tr><td>OCTUBRE 2018</td>
      <td>10,00 BsS</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**Estructura de mis 2 tablas**

```
#   Nombre              Tipo            Cotejamiento    Atributos   Nulo            Predeterminado

#ESTRUCTURA DE LA TABLA PAGOS

1   idPrimaria          int(11)                                     No  Ninguna     AUTO_INCREMEN
2   user                varchar(12)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
3   monto               varchar(100)        latin1_spanish_ci       No  Ninguna 
4   concepto            varchar(200)        latin1_spanish_ci       No  Ninguna 
5   mes_de_pago         varchar(30)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
6   afiliacion          varchar(30)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
7   banco_origen        varchar(200)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
8   banco_destino       varchar(200)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
9   nro_transfÍndice    varchar(100)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
10  ci_nro_cuenta       varchar(20)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
11  fecha_transf        timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAM
12  fecha_pago          timestamp       No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
13  status_pago         varchar(30)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna 
14  motivo_rechazo      text            latin1_spanish_ci   


#ESTRUCTURA DE LA TABLA PEDIDO

1   idPrimaria          int(11)                                     No  Ninguna     AUTO_INCREMENT
2   usuario             varchar(200)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
3   monto               varchar(10)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
4   nro_transfÍndice    varchar(100)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
5   banco_emisor        varchar(100)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
6   banco_destino       varchar(100)    latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
7   fecha_transf        timestamp                                   Sí  NULL
8   ci_nro_cuenta       varchar(20)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
9   status_pedido       varchar(50)     latin1_spanish_ci           No  Ninguna
10  fecha_pedido        timestamp                                   Sí              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
11  fecha_aprobacion    timestamp                                   Sí  NULL
12  motivo_rechazo      text            latin1_spanish_ci           Sí  NULL
13  fecha_rechazo       timestamp                                   Sí  NULL
```

Comment: No entiendo bien cómo estás organizando los datos... me pregunto si traes los datos consultando dos tablas y si las mismas no se relacionan, de ser así podrías traer todos los datos en una sola consulta y sería más fácil calcular el total. En los `while` tampoco se ve claro de dónde sale la 2ª columna o qué ocurre en ese 2º `while`. Para mostrar un total, la lógica a seguir sería construir todas las filas con sus tres columnas y sus datos dentro del bucle y fuera del bucle agregar otra fila parecida a esto: `'<tr><td colspan="3">TOTAL: '.$valorTotal.'</td></tr>`

Comment: Si son 2 query diferentes ya que no se relacionan de forma directa una es una tabla de pagos y la otra de mensualidades, por eso las tengo que recuperar con 2 query diferentes

Comment: Ya, pero es raro que no se relacionen por algún `ID`... si de hecho quieres mostrar esa info junta es porque tienen relación de alguna manera (me refiero a la lógica real que debería seguir tu programa), otra cosa es que los datos no se hayan diseñado relacionados, lo cual podría hacerse. Pero ese es otro asunto. Para mostrar el total al final, tienes que poner algo como esto cuando termines de llenar todas la filas: `'<tr><td colspan="3" align="right">TOTAL: '.$valorTotal.'</td></tr>';` el `colspan` es para que, en esa fila última junte las tres celdas que tiene tu tabla en una sola.

Comment: Si en `$j['monto_total2']` hay varios valores que quieres sumar dentro del 2º `while`, entonces puedes declarar una variable, e irla acumulando dentro. Declaras `$valorTotal=0;` fuera de todos los `while` y dentro del 2º pones algo así: `while ($j = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_apa)) 
      {
        $valorTotal= valorTotal +  $j['monto_total2'];
      }` y luego muestras el valor acumulado en la última fila como ya se indicó en el anterior comentario.

Comment: No se relacionan por ID ya que son tablas que reciben datos diferentes, en uno se reciben pago de mensualidades y en el otro datos de pago por servicios, productos, pedidos, etc etc y lo que quiero lograr es que se muestre en una misma tabla de meses lo acumulado en mis 2 query, los datos los esta recuperando pero lo que me esta comiendo es este html

Comment: Si no se puede meter es dato luego me pongo a hacer un join a ver que tal me sale, pero de pronto quisiera lograr poner el dato `$m` debajo del enunciado **Mensualidades** de mi tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que realizas un bucle `while` dentro de otro bucle `while`. Si lo piensas un momento, lo que sucede es que cuando realizas la primera iteración del bucle más externo, se ejecutan todas las iteraciones del bucle interno. Luego que todas las iteraciones del bucle interno se realizan entonces continúan las iteraciones restantes del bucle externo. El resultado ya lo puedes ver.

Mi solución a este problema es usar un `array` para que almacenes los datos de tu consulta `apa`, luego ejecutas un solo bucle `while` para obtener los datos de la consulta `epe` y generar la tabla.

Como te comenta @ACedano, sería preferible traer los datos en una sola consulta, usando `JOIN` sobre las tablas si estas se relacionan.

Para que esto funcione, estoy asumiendo que la cantidad de registros de la consulta `apa` es igual a la cantidad de registros de la consulta `epe`.

Quedaría algo así:

```js
//PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS
  $resultado_estadistica .= "<h4>ESTADISTICA DE PEDIDOS ENTREGADOS</h4>";

  $resultado_estadistica .= '<table id="estadistica" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Mes</th> 
  <th>Ventas Mensual</th>
  <th>Mensualidades </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';
  
  //setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_VE.UTF-8');
  // ======Hasta aqui todo igual=======
  
  // aqui declaramos un array para almacenar los datos apa
  $datos_apa = array();
  
  // ahora guardamos los datos de la consulta apa en nuestro array con la function array_push()
  while ($j = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_apa)) {
    array_push($datos_apa, $j['monto_total2']);
    }
    
  // Ya tenemos nuestros datos apa
  
  // Ahora construimos la tabla
  
  // Primero iniciamos un contador para extraer los datos de nuestro array
  $i = 0;
  
  while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_epe)){

    $dateGroup = strtoupper($l['dateGroup']);
    $monto_total = $l['monto_total'];
    $venta_mensual = number_format($monto_total, 2, ',', '.');
    
    // aqui cargamos la variable $monto_total2
    $monto_total2 = $datos_apa[$i];
    $mensualidad = number_format($monto_total2, 2, ',', '.');
    
    // ahora escribimos la tabla
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<tr>';
    
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'.$dateGroup.'</td>';
    
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'.$venta_mensual.' BsS'.'</td>';
    
    $resultado_estadistica .= '<td>'.$mensualidad.' BsS'.'</td>';
    
    $resultado_estadistica .= '</tr>';
    
    // Por último debemos aumentar el contador
    $i = $i + 1;
      
     //$resultado_estadistica .= ' ';
  }   

  $resultado_estadistica .= '</tbody></table>';
```

De esta forma puedes darle formato a tu tabla usando los datos que obtienes en las consultas `apa` y `epe`.

Sin embargo debo apuntarte algo muy importante. Los datos de `apa` y `epe` no se relacionan de ninguna manera según la forma en que los consultas.

Puedes tener problemas por ejemplo si la consulta de datos `apa` trae menos registros que la consulta de datos `epe`, en el bucle `while` saltaría un error de índice no válido al tratar de acceder a tu array de datos `apa`.

Otra cosa que pudiese pasar es que los datos `apa` no tengan el mismo orden que los datos `epe`. Entonces tu tabla no tendría ningún sentido.

Debes buscar la forma de realizar la consulta usando un `JOIN`, eso te asegura que los datos son relacionados y además realizas una solo petición al servidor.

Saludos y espero que esta respuesta te ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Tratare de implementar tu sugerencia y estaba tratando de hacer un JOIN de la siguiente manera `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pagos.fecha_pago,'%M %Y') AS dateGroup2, DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha_pedido,'%M %Y') AS dateGroup, SUM(CASE WHEN pedidos.status_pedido = 'ENTREGADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Monto_Pedidos', SUM(CASE WHEN pagos.status_pago = 'APROBADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Monto_Pagos' FROM pedidos INNER JOIN pagos ON DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha_pedido,'%M %Y') = DATE_FORMAT(pagos.fecha_pago,'%M %Y') GROUP BY dateGroup, dateGroup2 ORDER by STR_TO_DATE(dateGroup, '%m/%d') DESC LIMIT 0 , 10` y no me da

Comment: Que error te arroja? o simplemente no te trae nada?

Comment: trae datos incorrectos, ejemplo en vez de darme un valor de 100 me da un valor de 984500 no logro comprender donde esta mi error

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el formato de ambas tablas? Me refiero a los nombres de los campos y sus tipos de datos. Así podemos ver de qué manera las podemos relacionar.

Comment: Por otro lado. ¿Has probado la solución que publiqué?

Comment: Si lo intente y me da un error de sintaxis Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting

Comment: He editado mi consulta y he colocado las estructuras de mis 2 tablas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88219/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-jose-m-herrera-v).